# error insert bd value datapicker laravel ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.4

hi guys have a problem to insert value in one datapicker return null this my ajax code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // add a new post
    $(document).on('click', '.add-modal', function() {
        $('.modal-title').text('Add');
        $('#addModal').modal('show');
    });
    $('.modal-footer').on('click', '.add', function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'posts',
            data: {
                '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
                'title': $('#title_add').val(),
                'content': $('#content_add').val(),
                'date':$('#fecha').val(),
                'date2':$('#fecha').val()
            }<script/>
```

and my Store controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $this->rules);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Response::json(array('errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()));
    } else {
        $post = new Post();
        $post->title = $request->title;
        $post->content = $request->content;
        $post->fechai =  Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $request->fecha);
        $post->fechaf =   $request->datepicker1;
        $post->user_id = \Auth::user()->id;
        $post->save();
        return response()->json($post);
    }
}
```

why two datapicker return null

view

```
 <div class="form-group" >
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="date2">Fecha 2:</label>
   <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker1" name="fecha1">
         <div class="input-group-addon">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
       </div>
            </div>
                    </div>
```

this my datapicker i thin my ajax no work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `date` as $_POST keys not `fecha`

```
 $post->fechai =  Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $request->date);
```

your id is incorrect

`'date':$('#datepicker1').val(),`

Comment: hi in $request->date return null

Comment: then that element doesn't have a value

Comment: or the element isn't present on the page

Comment: put this error  Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', null)

Comment: do a var_dump($request), if your date isn't there then you aren't sending it via ajax

Comment: check my datapicker

Comment: your id is incorrect so the value is null, see my updated question

Comment: return null again

Comment: is the key/value in the `var_dump($request)`?

Comment: so you have the key but the value is null, if you `alert($('#datepicker1').val())` do you get the date?

Comment: yeah i get value my datapicker

Comment: then you should get the value in the php as well, can you post a screenshot of you xhr request?

Comment: the bottom part of the headers where the values are